# How to install jdk1.8 and set its path on fedora28?

Tags: fedora, java, jdk

How to install jdk1.8  and set its path on fedora28?

Comment: Which JDK do you mean? Oracle JDK which you have to download from Oracle's website or the openjdk which should be available through the packet manager?

Comment: Oracle JDK and how to install and set its path.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to install the Oracle JDK on Fedora you have to options (check your CPU's architecture).

- Download the tar.gz file from Oracle's website
- Download the rpm file from Oracle's website

#### Option 1 - tar.gz

IMHO the easiest and less invasive option is to download the tar.gz file. Let's assume you downloaded the file `jdk-8u161-linux-x64.tar.gz`. After the download open a terminal and extract the file to an appropriate place, eg a sub folder in your user's home directory `/home/myuser/programs` by executing

```
cd /home/myuser/programs
tar -xvzf <PATH-TO-DOWNLOADED-FILE>/jdk-8u161-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

After that the you have a directory `jdk1.8.0_161` in `/home/myuser/programs` which you can now reference.
To have all the binaries in `/home/myuser/programs/jdk1.8.0_161/bin` available use

```
export JAVA_HOME=/home/myuser/programs/jdk1.8.0_161
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

This sets the environment variable `JAVA_HOME` to the directory where you extracted all the files and puts all binaries in the sub dir `bin` into the environment variable `PATH`.

Test it with:

```
java -version
```

The output should be:

```
java version "1.8.0_161"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_161-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.161-b12, mixed mode)
```

After that was successful remember to persist the environment settings by adding them to you `~/.profile` file or  `~/.bashrc`.

#### Option 2 - rpm file

Discalimer: I have not tested this way.

For this way you need root access. After you downloaded the rpm file you may want to check if all requirements to install the JDK are matched by executing

```
rpm -i --test  <PATH-TO-DOWNLOADED-FILE>/jdk-8u161-linux-x64.rpm
```

After that was successfull, change to **root** (`su root`) and install the rpm by

```
rpm -i <PATH-TO-DOWNLOADED-FILE>/jdk-8u161-linux-x64.rpm
```

Maybe you can also use `sudo`

```
sudo rpm -i <PATH-TO-DOWNLOADED-FILE>/jdk-8u161-linux-x64.rpm
```

After installing the rpm file you maybe have to add the binaries to you `PATH` variable as above (see option 1).